# Is it possible to use one common repository for different entities in Spring data JPA

Tags: spring-data

For example, I have entities like Car, Person, Customer. 
I need generic method like findBy using Specification in my repository class.
I do not want to write different repository for each of the entities.
Is it possible to create one common repository for all the entities and use it in my application.
How to create the instance of the repository with different entity types.
I am currently using spring boot for my testing

Answer (score 2):

If your code is structured as:

```
@MappedSuperclass class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {}

@Entity class Car      extends AbstractEntity {}

@Entity class Person   extends AbstractEntity {}

@Entity class Customer extends AbstractEntity {}
```

you can do this:

```
@NoRepositoryBean interface AbstractEntityRepository<T extends AbstractEntity>
                            extends JpaRepository<T, ...>
                                    , JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {}

interface CarRepository extends AbstractEntityRepository<Car> {}

interface PersonRepository extends AbstractEntityRepository<Person> {}

interface CustomerRepository extends AbstractEntityRepository<Customer> {}
```

This will give you access to methods that take a `Specification<EntityType>` on all your repositories through `JpaSpecificationExecutor`.

Comment: I have tried this. But my concern was that I need to create individual repositories for each of the entities though they all extend method from the   abstract repository and in my application I would need to create instance of each of these repositories depending on the entity. Is there any way to avoid this.

Comment: I have never tried this myself and don't recommend a design like this but you can try removing the `@NoRepositoryBean` from `AbstractEntityRepository` and then wiring it at the place of use as `@Autowired AbstractEntityRepository<Car> carRepository`, etc.

Comment: When I remove @NoRepositoryBean from I always get this error: Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property query found for type Person!

Comment: If I provide custom implementation for the abstract repository above said error doesn't occur. But @Autowired is not creating instance of repository. Repository is null, hence I get nullpointer exception.